# How to replace character of some banned word of a string with star? banned words are stored in another text file

Tags: python

```
if x in words:
            for c in words:
                x= x.replace(c, "*")
                return x
    print("".join(x))
```

Every character in `x` which is banned word text file should be replaced by *.

Comment: You haven't really told us the problem with your code.

Comment: maybe use `len(c)` to see how many `*` you have to put - ie to put 5 starts - `"*" * 5`

Comment: How to compare strings stored in a set with a string stored in a list?

Answer (score 1):

A very naive implementation would be to loop over all banned words and perform a string replace

```
for banned_word in banned_words:
    input_string = input_string.replace(banned_word, '*' * len(banned_word))
```

Comment: Using `for banned_word in sorted(banned_words, key=len)` will give better coverage.

Comment: @ZachGates what do you mean by better coverage? If anything it's probably better to sort by length reversed so longer matches are replaced first - better to have `*******` than `****ers` no?

Comment: Right, meant to have `reverse=True` there.

Comment: i have to replace in the user_input(string) some banned words with *. For that i first saved the text file under the And then print the user input with * sign replacing the banned words. Example: "what the heck" is user input. and heck comes under the banned words. so my output should be represented as "what the ****"